# Ubuntu 20.10 wifi adapter not found

Tags: networking

So I dual booted ubuntu (20.10) and the wifi icon is not even there amongst Bluetooth and Power Off. When I found the wifi settings it says  'No Wi-Fi Adapter Found'.I have a Realtek 8821CE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC adapter.And it is working on windows (as I said I dual booted it).Unfortunately I don't have ethernet port on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu doesn't have drivers for every WIFI card or sometimes the drivers supplied by manfacteurs don't work.

In this case there is a driver available but you'll need to build it..

```
https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
```

Instructions for building

```
sudo apt install bc module-assistant build-essential dkms
sudo m-a prepare

sudo git clone git@github.com:tomaspinho/rtl8821ce.git

cd  rtl882lce.git
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```